# Store, retrieve and delete settings in C# Registry

Tags: c#

My code writes, reads, and removes program settings in the registry. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and my target Framework is .NET Framework 4.8.

I'm looking for more elegant functions.
Is there error handling I missed in these functions?
How can I optimize the code?

I have the following functions at the moment:

```
public static class Settings
{

    public static void SaveSetting(string sCompanyName, string sAppName, string sSection, string sValueName, string sValue)
    {
        RegistryKey softKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
        RegistryKey compKey = softKey.CreateSubKey(sCompanyName);
        RegistryKey appKey = compKey.CreateSubKey(sAppName);
        RegistryKey secKey = appKey.CreateSubKey(sSection);
        secKey.SetValue(sValueName, sValue);
    }

    public static string GetSetting(string sCompanyName, string sAppName, string sSection, string sValueName, string sDefault)
    {
      
        RegistryKey softKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
        RegistryKey compKey = softKey.CreateSubKey(sCompanyName);
        RegistryKey appKey = compKey.CreateSubKey(sAppName);
        RegistryKey secKey = appKey.CreateSubKey(sSection);

        return (string)secKey.GetValue(sValueName, sDefault);
    }

    public static void DeleteSetting(string sCompanyName, string sAppName, string sSection, string sValueName)
    {
        RegistryKey softKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
        RegistryKey compKey = softKey.CreateSubKey(sCompanyName);
        RegistryKey appKey = compKey.CreateSubKey(sAppName);
        RegistryKey secKey = appKey.CreateSubKey(sSection);

        if (secKey.GetValue(sValueName) != null)
        {
            secKey.DeleteValue(sValueName);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to echo [BCdotWEB's observations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/255415/224104), they are all valid ones.

Rather I would like to focus on the [RegisteryKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) API usage.

#### `OpenSubKey`

Let's take a look at the [signature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_OpenSubKey_System_String_System_Boolean_) of the method first:

```cs
public Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey? OpenSubKey (string name, bool writable);
```

- As you can see it may return a `RegisteryKey` or a `null`. So, it might make sense to check the result of this operation against `null` before you call any method on it to prevent `NullReferenceException`.
- The `name` parameter can work as a path as well. So, you could call `OpenSubKey` like this:

```cs
.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows", true);
//OR
.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows", true);
```

Now, let's look at the Exceptions:

- `ArgumentNullException`: name is null.
- `ObjectDisposedException`: The RegistryKey is closed ([closed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.close?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) keys cannot be accessed).
- `SecurityException`: The user does not have the permissions required to access the registry key in the specified mode.

The first two cases are irrelevant in your solution. But the 3rd one is quite important. There is a chance that the given entry is `readonly` for the current user. So, it might make sense to prepare for this situation.

I would also encourage you to check out the [RegistrySecurity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.registrysecurity) and [RegistryRights](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.registryrights) pages to learn how to grant access on demand.

#### `CreateSubKey`

Let's start with the [signature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_CreateSubKey_System_String_) again:

```cs
public Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey CreateSubKey (string subkey);
```

Even though the signature does not indicate that the return value can be `null`, the remarks of the *Returns* section does:

> The newly created subkey, or null if the operation failed.

Please also bear in mind the second part of this section:

> If a zero-length string is specified for subkey, the current RegistryKey object is returned.

- If someone calls your API by passing an empty string for example to the `sAppName` parameter then your `appKey` will point to the same entry as `compKey`. Your create/delete could cause harm in this case. So, always check users' inputs before you start using them.
- If someone calls your API by passing `null` for instance to the `sAppName` parameter then it will throw an `ArgumentNullException`. Yet again, check your params!

You should also consider to catch and handle gracefully the following exceptions:

- `SecurityException`: The user does not have the permissions required to create or open the registry key.
- `UnauthorizedAccessException`: The RegistryKey cannot be written to; for example, it was not opened as a writable key , or the user does not have the necessary access rights.

#### `GetValue`

Yet again start with the [signature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_GetValue_System_String_):

```cs
public object GetValue (string name);

public object GetValue (string name, object defaultValue);
```

As you can see it returns with an `object`. (That's why you have cast it to `string`). Which might be okay in this particular case. But image a situation that your API gains popularity and consumers of your API want to use it to read/write other types as well not just strings. You have two options then:

1. Introduce overloads (so one method group for each datatype)
2. Utilize generics (so one method group with generic type parameter)

In the latter case it might make sense to make use of the [GetValueKind](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluekind), which returns a [RegistryValueKind](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind) enum. Based on that value you can dynamically determine how to cast the retrieved value.

Answer (score 3):

Quick remarks:

- When you're copy-pasting code, you should realize you're doing the wrong thing. The first four lines of each of your methods are exactly the same, and thus should become a method that returns a `RegistryKey`.
- Do not needlessly abbreviate. `softKey`, `compKey`, `appKey` and `secKey` are all unclear.
- Do not use Hungarian notation. Even if the type isn't clear from a parameter's name, your IDE will tell you what type it is.
- Why doesn't `DeleteSetting` use `GetSetting` to retrieve the value?

Comment: Missed one (important?) thing. `RegistryKey` implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @aepot Ah, didn't check that, but that's also very important, yes.